# Fit a long table content inside one PDF page with itext 7 and C#

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf, itext7

I have a Windows desktop application written in C#.
The program should print an invoice of sales.

I can loop and fill the table with this code:

```
while (detalle.Read())
{
    celda_detalle = new Cell().Add(new Paragraph(detalle["Descripcion"].ToString())
    .SetFontSize(10)).SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.LEFT).SetMargins(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f).SetPadding(0f)
    .SetBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
    tabla_detalle.AddCell(celda_detalle);

    celda_detalle = new Cell().Add(new Paragraph(detalle["Precio"].ToString())
   .SetFontSize(10)).SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.RIGHT).SetMargins(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f).SetPadding(0f)
   .SetBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
    tabla_detalle.AddCell(celda_detalle);

    celda_detalle = new Cell().Add(new Paragraph(detalle["Descu"].ToString())
  .SetFontSize(10)).SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.RIGHT).SetMargins(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f).SetPadding(0f)
  .SetBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
    tabla_detalle.AddCell(celda_detalle);
    alto += 72;
}
```

To get the table height I use this code:

```
LayoutResult esquema = tabla_detalle.CreateRendererSubTree().SetParent(document.GetRenderer()).Layout(new LayoutContext(new LayoutArea(1, new Rectangle(0, 0, necessaryWidth, 10000.0F))));
                float alto_tabla = esquema.GetOccupiedArea().GetBBox().GetHeight();
```

The pdf always create two pages and I need to fit all in one page

[image]

Comment: Hi, what is your question? Can you also make sure your code sample is small and reproducible? Right now it refers to e.g. `detalle` and we don't know what it is. Also, have you tried decreasing the font size?

Comment: Hello, I can fix this issue adding margins at the page size calculation: Document doc2 = new Document(pdf, new PageSize(necessaryWidth + 10 * 2, alto_tabla + 10 * 2));